# How do install Ubuntu 22.04 desktop in Virtualbox for Mac OS ventura. I keep getting the error as attached in the screenshot

Tags: macos, virtualbox

[image]

Installing ubuntu on Mac OS Ventura using Virtualbox

Comment: Does VirtualBox claim support for an unreleased beta OS?

Answer (score 2):

Use VirtualBox 7.0.2 (released recently on https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads )

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).